# How to get device_id for Pushover.net login?

Tags: pushover

I must be missing something. I'm trying to make an application that will just receive notifications, just a simple C# program.

In the messages request, they say "Include the user secret and device_id parameters in the GET request ".

The device_id is not displayed anywhere on my login page. Thus, I said, it has to come thru the "device registration", that is, I though, device registration now, at this moment, this application registers as a device.

If I do the device registration thru https://api.pushover.net/1/devices.json, say with the name I already created, a "Chrome", it returns error message 
"name":["has already been taken"] (which comes also when Chrome is stopped) ; if I try a new name that's not given before, it will actually register a new device on the website. If I give the name of an application I registered on their page, it's "name":["is invalid"].

I don't get it..., but they put some effort into misleading directions...

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that seems usable is adding a device programatically and retaining somewhere the id from the response.